# Origin of “hold from” as an idiom meaning “love, like, respect” in European languages

Tags: semantics, idiomaticity

Several European languages known to me have a verbal phrase idiom literally translatable as "hold from", expressing various kinds of positive attitude:

- Dutch *houden van* "love"
- Finnish *pitää -stA* "like"
- Hebrew *hikhzik mi-* "respect, hold in high regard"
  (Hebrew isn't technically a European language, but it can be argued to be one in a broad sense)

It seems most likely that the remesblance is due to calquing. Three questions:

1. If this is so, what is the origin of the calque?
2. What other languages have comparable idioms?
3. What is the semantic link between "hold from" and "like" etc.?

Comment: German: *etwas von jemandem/etwas halten* (lit. *to hold something from someone/something*) = to think sth of someone/something; in this form (or with *viel* (= "much") etc.) in a positive sense, i.e. to approve of; with *nichts* (= "nothing") or simiar negative quantifications in a negative sense, to disapprove of

Comment: Can it be that "I hold from you" is used in the sense of "I get high / get stunned / get stoned / get petrified/ hold my breath / freeze from [how gtreat is] you"?

Comment: As for the semantic link, I could imagine something like "This gives a lot to me", "I hold on to it (because it is of value to me)", "I keep it in my heart" etc.

Comment: Also, French has *tenir à*.

Answer (score 1):

As Lemontree has mentioned "etwas von jemandem halten" is a very common phrase in German. "Was halten Sie davon?" = "What do you think of it?". "Ich halte nichts davon" = "I have a low opinion of it". I think it is a quintessentially German idiom. Presumably is was calqued from German to Dutch, Finnish and Yiddish > Modern Hebrew.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected German might be the source. Does the phrase used without an adverb have a default positive connotation, i.e. does *Ich halte davon* mean something like "I like it"?

Comment: No, "ich halte davon" does not work on its own.

Comment: As fdb said, without an adverbial it is ungrammatical, however *Ich halte etwas davon*, with *etwas* (= "something") being actually a neutral element like in the base form in *etwas von jemandem halten* (= *to think sth of soe*), it has positive meaning, so this seems to be the more default-like.

Comment: No line of argumentation or any source are provided here to justify that the German phrase is the source or that it even has any connection to the phrases in the other languages.

Comment: And I would be interested why High German should be the source of the Dutch expression *houden van*.

Comment: The  *Etymologisch woordenboek*(van Veen, van der Sijs) mentions an original meaning that might be impossible to bring in line with the German expression. "De uitdrukking houden van betekende in het middelnl. ‘iets in leen hebben van’, ‘iemands vazal zijn’, vandaar ‘om iem. geven’ en ten slotte ‘iem. beminnen’." So, basically it is supposed to have had the original meaning "to be someone's vassal".